# Delete using active record

Tags: activerecord, ruby-on-rails-3.1

How to achieve below query in ActiveRecord ?

```
"delete from model where date(created_at)=#{some_date}"
```

where created_at is sql datetime field.

One option I can think is calculate

```
start_date = starting time of the day
end_date = end time of the day
```

and

```
Model.delete_all('created_at' >= start_date, 'created_at' < end_date)
```

Any other clean option ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming database you are using is MySql and start_date is a date object.

Use mysql [`DATE_FORMAT`](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_date_format.asp) function

```
Model.delete_all("DATE_FORMAT(created_at, '%Y-%m-%d') >= ?",
                 start_date.strftime("%Y-%m-%d"))
```